# ipage mail() configuration

Tags: php, email, host

I have this bit of code:

```
$to = "igoralves@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: $from");
```

I am hosted on ipage. The service does not work. So they told me that: "
"There is no need to manage any changes on php.ini file. Please use the SendMail path - /usr/sbin/sendmail in your script."

How can I change the code?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if is still useful for you, but in order to send email from ipage using php you need to set the "From: " field in the mail function as 'From: /usr/sbin/sendmail'."\r\n".

So in your case the variable $from would be $from = 'From: /usr/sbin/sendmail'."\r\n"

I myself tried this code and it fixed the problem.

Best regards.

Comment: 'From' field must contain email, not the path to 'sendmail'